# Connecting two USB *clients* together (SiK radio problem)

Tags: usb

I need to connect a typical USB SiK radio to a USB *client*.

The other radio is plugged into a PC so is not a problem. But I don't have a Host device for the other end, and while I can provide +5 power, obviously I need something (ideally a single chip or very small solution) to act as a Host, so that the radio can communicate with the USB client device.

I suppose an Arduino could be programmed for this but I'm looking for a way to solve this more elegantly.

Comment: So you need a host (with two ports) and software to bridge the two. I suggest a raspberry pi. And besides this, it looks like a shopping question. Those are [considered off-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: whatever a "SiK radio" is! Anyways, removing the shopping question so that we don't have to close this.

Comment: Silicon potassium radio? I think you should say what a SiK radio is.

Comment: I didn't really consider this to be a "shopping" question since I doubted that there would be an off the shelf solution. In any case, SiK radios are common inexpensive 433 or 915mhz telemetry radios. E.g.: https://store.mrobotics.io/mRo-SiK-Telemetry-Radio-V2-915Mhz-p/mro-sikv2.htm

Comment: From providing a +5V to having a USB host is a VERY big distance...Honestly, being a sort of USB person, this kind of questions feels pretty insulting.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino doesn't sound like the platform of choice here, but you're clearly on the right path:

You're looking for a platform that makes it easy to configure your controller's USB interface as host.

An easy solution would be a fully blown application processor board – an Odroid, a raspberry Pi, or a lot of other Linux boards would be as easy as it gets to set this up.

On the lower-power, less comfortable scale of things would be microcontroller with native USB support, together with a somewhat sensible OS for these that makes USB handling easy. Your application sounds a lot like ARM's [mbed](https://mbed.com) platform's target use case, so I'd start there – they have a whole galery of supported devices, starting from USD 5 eval boards to fully blown ARM computers.

Personally, that would be something you can hack together with nothing but a QFN breakout board and a Cypress PSoC4 running ChibiOS, but honestly, that's pretty far from beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be solving this with a Raspberry Pi Zero W. This will provide the USB OTG master I need to talk to the client device, and I can use the Zero W's onboard Wi-Fi for now instead of the telemetry radios. If I want to add the radios later, it will be easy, since I have compatible versions that could connect to the Zero W's serial interface. Thanks all!